# Python - Gtk.TreeView with Gtk.ListStore get selected index

Tags: python, list, gtk3, gtktreeview

i want to store items in a gtk-list and i decided to use the Gtk TreeView as List. Because i am quite new to python and gtk i want to store my elements as string representation in the TreeView and in a seperate python-list the according objects.

So if i delete an item in the Gtk list (via key-event), i have to be able to determine the selected row index to delete the correct python-list element.

My actual question is: **How can i determine the index of the selected row in a Gtk.TreeView?**

Thank you for your help!

PS: I am using Python 3 with GTK 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Gtk.TreeViewSelection. You can get it from Gtk.TreeView (Assuming you have id column in your GtkTreeModel (GtkListStore or GtkTreeStore) constructor).

```
    from gi.repository import Gtk

    def yourcallback ( selection ):
       model,list_iter = selection.get_selected ()
       if list_iter != None:
       # Debugging mode, uncomment to activate
       # print "row index = " + model[list_iter][column_number_that_you_want]


  # alternate
  # def yourcallback (path, column, data):
  #   ........


    ..........
    yourtvselection           = yourtv.get_selection ()        
    yourtvselection.connect ( "changed" , yourcallback)
    # alternative signal
    # yourtv.connect ("row-activated", yourcallback)
```